# Is it a bug of Qt libraries or of my own app?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webkit

I've written an app using Qt library(both 4.7 and 4.7.1 have this problem), and this app mainly deals with webkit(display web pages) and Qt-webkit bridging(maps C++ class to Javascript object). But got the following segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5585db7 in QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::allDone (this=0x86bb20)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnectionchannel.cpp:620
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
620     if (reply->d_func()->expectContent() && reply->d_func()->autoDecompress && !reply->d_func()->streamEnd)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5585db7 in QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::allDone (
    this=0x86bb20)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnectionchannel.cpp:620
#1  0x00007ffff5586992 in QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::_q_receiveReply (
    this=0x86bb20)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnectionchannel.cpp:397
#2  0x00007ffff558829a in QHttpNetworkConnectionChannel::qt_metacall (
    this=0x86bb20, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, 
    _id=<value optimized out>, _a=0x7fffffffd8c0)
    at .moc/release-shared/moc_qhttpnetworkconnectionchannel_p.cpp:92
#3  0x00007ffff51ec0f8 in QMetaObject::activate (sender=0x8655f0, 
    m=<value optimized out>, local_signal_index=<value optimized out>, 
    argv=0x8a9e20) at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp:3272
#4  0x00007ffff55ed678 in QAbstractSocketPrivate::canReadNotification (
    this=0x865610)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp:639
#5  0x00007ffff55dc791 in QReadNotifier::event (this=<value optimized out>, 
    e=0x1) at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/network/socket/qnativesocketengine.cpp:1103
#6  0x00007ffff5a67d5f in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper (this=0x61b840, 
    receiver=0x965270, e=0x7fffffffdee0)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/gui/kernel/qapplication.cpp:4396
#7  0x00007ffff5a6e94b in QApplication::notify (this=0x7fffffffe1f0, 
    receiver=0x965270, e=0x7fffffffdee0)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/gui/kernel/qapplication.cpp:4277
#8  0x00007ffff51d60a4 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal (
    this=0x7fffffffe1f0, receiver=0x965270, event=0x7fffffffdee0)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp:732
#9  0x00007ffff5203a3a in QCoreApplication::sendEvent (source=0x624b20)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.h:215
#10 socketNotifierSourceDispatch (source=0x624b20)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp:110
#11 0x00007ffff26f08c2 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff26f4748 in ?? () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff26f48fc in g_main_context_iteration ()
   from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff5203bcc in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents (this=0x6210d0, 
    flags=<value optimized out>)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp:415
#15 0x00007ffff5b18bcf in QGuiEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents (
    this=0x86bb20, flags=<value optimized out>)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/gui/kernel/qguieventdispatcher_glib.cpp:204
#16 0x00007ffff51d53f5 in QEventLoop::processEvents (
    this=<value optimized out>, flags=...)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qeventloop.cpp:149
#17 0x00007ffff51d5646 in QEventLoop::exec (this=0x7fffffffe150, flags=...)
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qeventloop.cpp:201
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#18 0x00007ffff51d7484 in QCoreApplication::exec ()
    at /var/tmp/qt-src/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp:1009
#19 0x00000000004064b4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2f8)
    at ../myPlatform/main.cpp:10
```

Comment: It would help if we had an example of the source, otherwise it can be rather difficult to fix the problem.

Comment: Nowbody will be able to tell you if you do not provide a minimal example of with own source code.

Comment: Your own app. (Just guessing.)

Answer (score 0):

The warning: "Source file is more recent than executable." is strange. Did you compile the Qt sources? Or do you use the sources and headers from a recent version and the libraries from an older version?